# why dir([dataDIR 'P*/*.mat']) does not work in matlab?

Tags: matlab, directory, wildcard

I have the following matlab file in the following folder and subfolders :

`dataDIR
       P1
        p1_file.mat
       P2
        p2_file.mat`

I would like to recover a list of all the *.file

These following lines work fine :

```
dir([dataDIR 'P*/']) 
dir([dataDIR '*.mat']) 
dir([dataDIR '*myfile*.mat'])
```

Then when I want multiple wildcard *, one at the subfolder and one at the file name, it does not find anything.

```
dir([dataDIR 'P*/*.mat'])
```

I would like to search directly in the folders and subfolders without having to use a loop.

I am using Matlab R2015b and windows 7.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. Provide a [Mcve]

Comment: Just did, thank you in advance

Comment: Still not reproducible. Where is dataDIR located (its path)? And what is  current path of your MATLAB? Is path of dataDIR added to your MATLAB search path? If  it is added, is there any other directory named dataDIR in your MATLAB search path that's over-riding that?

Comment: the dataDIR path is : `C:\Users\Labo\Documents\MATLAB\dataDIR`, yes it is added in the matlab path and no there are no other dataDIR in my matlab path.

Comment: are you saying that having one wildcard for P* folders then another one after the /*.mat works for you?

Comment: `dir([dataDIR 'P*/*.mat'])` this works and it should work for you as well. Are you missing a slash in `dataDIR`? i.e. is `dataDIR` this: `C:\Users\Labo\Documents\MATLAB\dataDIR` or is it 
this: `C:\Users\Labo\Documents\MATLAB\dataDIR\ ` ?

Comment: I have checked the path and it is there. I entered `dir(['C:/Users/Labo/Documents/MATLAB/dataDIR/' 'P*/*.mat'])
'C:/Users/Labo/Documents/MATLAB/dataDIR/P*/*.mat' not found.` Whereas when I put `patientDirList = dir(['C:/Users/Labo/Documents/MATLAB/anh/d05/FC_patients_data/' 'P1/*.mat']);` it finds the proper file (it works for P2, P3, etc. but not when it search for any P*)

Comment: what is there ?

Comment: matlab files in this form `file.mat`

Comment: So you actually have `P1` etc in `FC_patient_data` and not in `dataDIR`?

Comment: sorry for the mispelling let me update what I wrote. I entered `dir(['C:/Users/Labo/Documents/MATLAB/dataDIR/' 'P*/*.mat']);` It says `'C:/Users/Labo/Documents/MATLAB/dataDIR/P*/*.mat' not found.` Whereas when I put `dir(['C:/Users/Labo/Documents/MATLAB/dataDIR/' 'P1/*.mat']);` it finds the proper file (it works for P2, P3, etc. but not when it search for any P*)

Comment: not a reproducible issue

Comment: ok, thank you for trying. I tried to use regex as well. but same thing it does not recognize the `\w` or `\d` as being regex but interpret as actual character. Should the string put in `dir(string)` recognize regex expression?

Comment: mention your MATLAB version and OS in your question. Your issue may be reproducible for someone else with the same version/OS

Comment: Try the same with [**`ls`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html) instead of `dir` and see if that works

Comment: it gives the same thing. `P*` is still understood as characters and not as wildcard.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. It works for me with `ls` as well

Comment: I'll try on another computer with other versions of matlab and OS. Good to hear that it is suppose to work though.